# Position node to the left and right of an edge in DOT in graphviz

Tags: dot

I wrote the below DOT to generate a diagram. In addition to the nodes that are defined and laid out, I want to place one node to the left and another node to the right of the edge marked L, they should be close to L and in between NODE3 and NODE6.

I tried with some invisible nodes. The new nodes either go to the first row or the second row, but I want them to be in the new row between the first and second.

```
digraph g {
ranksep=0.5
graph [rankdir = "TB"];
graph [splines=ortho];

node [fontsize = "8"];
edge [];

node0 [label = "{NODE0}" shape = "record" ]; 
node1 [label = "{NODE1}" shape = "record" ];
node2 [label = "{NODE2}" shape = "record" ];
node3 [label = "{NODE3}" shape = "record" ];
node4 [label = "{NODE4}" shape = "record" ];

node5 [label = "{NODE5}" shape = "record" ]; 
node6 [label = "{NODE6}" shape = "record" ];
node7 [label = "{NODE7}" shape = "record" ];
node8 [label = "{NODE8}" shape = "record" ];
node9 [label = "{NODE9}" shape = "record" ];

node10 [label = "{NODE10}" shape = "record" ];
node11 [label = "{NODE11}" shape = "record" ];
node12 [label = "{NODE12}" shape = "record" ];

{rank=same; node0 -> node1 -> node2 -> node3 -> node4};
{rank=same; node5 -> node6 -> node7 -> node8 -> node9};
{rank=same; node10 -> node11 -> node12};
node1 -> node5;
node5 -> node3;
node3 -> node6[label="L"];
node7 -> node10;
node11 -> node8;
node9 -> node12;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?  I created a "point" node for the new ones to connect to within their rank.  Also fiddled with the arrowheads to give you an idea of the possibilities there.

```
digraph g {
ranksep=0.5
graph [rankdir = "TB"];
graph [splines=ortho];

node [fontsize = "8"];
edge [];

node0 [label = "{NODE0}" shape = "record" ]; 
node1 [label = "{NODE1}" shape = "record" ];
node2 [label = "{NODE2}" shape = "record" ];
node3 [label = "{NODE3}" shape = "record" ];
node4 [label = "{NODE4}" shape = "record" ];

node5 [label = "{NODE5}" shape = "record" ]; 
node6 [label = "{NODE6}" shape = "record" ];
node7 [label = "{NODE7}" shape = "record" ];
node8 [label = "{NODE8}" shape = "record" ];
node9 [label = "{NODE9}" shape = "record" ];

node10 [label = "{NODE10}" shape = "record" ];
node11 [label = "{NODE11}" shape = "record" ];
node12 [label = "{NODE12}" shape = "record" ];

nodenew1 [label="new1" shape=record];
nodenew2 [label="new2" shape=record];

{rank=same; node0 -> node1 -> node2 -> node3 -> node4};
{rank=same; node5 -> node6 -> node7 -> node8 -> node9};
{rank=same; node10 -> node11 -> node12};
node1 -> node5;
node5 -> node3;

{
rank = same;
nodenew1 -> nodepoint -> nodenew2 [ arrowhead=none]
}

nodepoint [shape=point]
node3 -> nodepoint [label="L" arrowhead=none];
nodepoint -> node6[label="L"];

node7 -> node10;
node11 -> node8;
node9 -> node12;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks TomServo for both a quick response plus a working answer. This solves what I am looking for for now. I need to expand this diagram more and if I encounter more issues, I will come back. You removed my first stumbling block.